# shuffle then sort a db query ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, activerecord, shuffle

I am trying to display a list of articles, sorted by day, but displayed randomly for each day.

This is what I have right now:

```
@articles = Article.all.shuffle.sort_by{|t| t.date_published}.reverse
```

I was thinking that the sort would take place on the shuffled array, but it doesn't seem like that is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have tried group_by by can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little insight on your code first: `all` will fetch ALL records from the database and pass it to your ruby code, this is resource and time consuming. Then the `shuffle`, `sort_by` and `reverse` are all executed by ruby. You will quickly hit performance issues as your database grow.

Your solution is to let your database server do that work. DB servers are very optimized for all sorting operations. So if you are for example using MySQL you should use this instead:

```
@articles = Article.order('`articles`.`date_published` DESC, RAND()')
```

Which will sort primarily by date_published in reverse order, and secondarily randomly for all articles of the same date

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It still doesn't seem to be working, though. I currently have the date in string type. Ill see if I can convert them all to a standardized type and then maybe it will work...

Comment: Your question is about sorting, my answer is about sorting. If you have problem with data type then it's another story, and you need to manage those 2 problems separately. Is the sorting works as expected with my answer?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be sorting with the answer you gave, but not all of the articles are sorting as desired, just some of them. And I think it is probably due to the date_published format, and them all not being perfectly the same since they are scraped form other sites.

Comment: Then you should validate/sanitize the date while importing the data from the scrap to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, here's a fun hack that *should* work:

```
@articles = Article.
  all.
  sort_by{|t| (t.date_published.beginning_of_day.to_i * 1000) + rand(100)}
```

This works by forcing all the dates to be the beginning of the day (so that everything published on '2015-02-19' for example will have the same `to_i` value.  Then you multiply by 1000 and add a random number between 0 and 100 for the sort (any number less than 1000 would work).